# Using require syntax instead of module in Typescript

Tags: typescript

In Typescript 0.9.1.1, if you want to import an external javascript library, you import it using the `require` function, instead of the `module` function that you used to use.

The question is, does this mean that Typescript 0.9.1.1 have `requirejs` as a core part of its libraries?

Comment: No, check out : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1 to learn the differences between internal `module` and external `requirejs` / `node`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - you can choose to use RequireJS or a different module loader if you prefer.

RequireJS isn't built in, so you need to add that if you want it.

The syntax for importing modules is compiled into either AMD (for loaders such as RequireJS) or CommonJS (for loaders such as the NodeJS module loader) - so anything that is compatible with one of those can be used.